Cartopy - Maps in LambertConformal projection
I would like to create a map in python using a LambertConformal projection from cartopy. But I would also like to have the plot plotted in a 2d conic shape. By running the code below, my plot is cut in half.
My code:
import pandas as pd
import gsw
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

def mapping_withproj(ax, bathymetry_lon, bathymetry_lat, bathymetry_depth, 
            data_lon, data_lat, var_interest, 
            label_cbar, title, vmin, vmax, cmap='plasma_r'):
        
         # Boundaries
        lon_min, lon_max = bathy_lon_coarse.min(), bathy_lon_coarse.max()
        lat_min, lat_max = bathy_lat_coarse.min(), bathy_lat_coarse.max()
        xlim = [lon_min, lon_max] # longitudes ~ [130, 300] 
        ylim = [lat_min, lat_max] # latitudes ~ [50, 90] 
        lower_space = 3 
        rect = mpath.Path([[xlim[0], ylim[0]],
                        [xlim[1], ylim[0]],
                        [xlim[1], ylim[1]],
                        [xlim[0], ylim[1]],
                        [xlim[0], ylim[0]],
                        ]).interpolated(20)
        proj_to_data   = ccrs.PlateCarree()._as_mpl_transform(ax) - ax.transData
        rect_in_target = proj_to_data.transform_path(rect)
        ax.set_boundary(rect_in_target)
        ax.set_extent([xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0] - lower_space, ylim[1]])

        # Bathymetry plotting
        mesh = ax.pcolormesh(bathymetry_lon, bathymetry_lat, bathymetry_depth, cmap='Blues_r', 
                                transform= ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=1)

        # Samples 
        scatter = ax.scatter(data_lon, data_lat, c=var_interest, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, 
                                s=40, edgecolor='black', linewidths=0.5, 
                                transform= ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=2)

        # Add colorbar
        cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax, orientation='vertical', fraction=0.025, pad=0.04)
        cbar.set_label(label_cbar)

        # Add coastlines, borders, and land features
        ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, linewidth=0.5, zorder=3)
        ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linewidth=0.5, zorder=4)
        ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='darkgray', edgecolor='k', zorder=5)
        ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')

        # Customize gridlines
        gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, x_inline=False,y_inline=False, crs= ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=0.5, color='gray', linestyle='--', zorder=6)
        gl.xlabels_top = False #avoid label on top of the graph
        gl.ylabels_right = False #avoid label on the right (color bar's place) of the graph
        gl.xlocator = plt.MaxNLocator(5) 
        gl.ylocator = plt.MaxNLocator(5)
        gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 14, 'color': 'gray'}
        gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 14, 'color': 'gray'}

        # Add title
        ax.set_title(title, fontsize=16)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-140, central_latitude=75, standard_parallels=(60, 80)))
mapping_withproj(ax, bathy_lon_coarse, bathy_lat_coarse, bathy_h_coarse,
        data_2020['Longitude_degE'], data_2020['Latitude_degN'], data_2020['Depth_m'],
        'Depth (m)', 'Sampling location depths', vmin=0, vmax=20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)  # Space between subplots
plt.show()

I have already tried to change the 'lower_space' variable to higher numbers (10, 30...) and I ended up with a full graph but with a lot of white space at the bottom of my plot.
My Output with lower_space = 3
My output with lower_space = 50 
Thank you in advance!
